# How to manage project CMake based plugins?

Tags: c++, cmake

Consider this project structure:

<sub>Complete example of the project: [another-ghasem/CMakePluginProblem](https://github.com/another-ghasem/CMakePluginProblem)</sub>

```sh
+ 
|
+-- plugin/
     +- plugin_1/
     +- plugin_2/
     +- plugin_3/
+-- CMakeLists.txt
+-- main.cpp
```

Those plugins are Shared Libraries created with CMake and will be linked to the root project. But the plugins dependencies are the problem (all the plugins have a [Target Alias](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#alias-targets) with [BUILD_INTERFACE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:BUILD_INTERFACE) include path: [plugin_2/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/another-ghasem/CMakePluginProblem/blob/main/plugin/plugin_2/CMakeLists.txt#L20-L22)).

##### How could we manage the non-generated but linked plugins?

Consider the `plugin_1` linked to `plugin_2` ([plugin_1/CMakeLists.txt#22](https://github.com/another-ghasem/CMakePluginProblem/blob/main/plugin/plugin_1/CMakeLists.txt#L22)):

```sh
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Project::plugin_2)
```

Here CMake could somehow handle the build order, but if we remove the `plugin_2` CMake will raise an error about it:

```sh
 Target "plugin_1" links to target "Project::plugin_2" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

By the way, we couldn't use an `if`-statement to check "if we have the needed plugin, then linked and define a macro to notice that we have the plugin". How could we handle these dependencies?

---

<sub>- **CMake Version**: `3.16` 

- **OS**: `Fedora 34`, `Ubuntu 18.04`</sub>

Comment: So rename it to `plugin_2` without the `::` or `add_subdirectory(../plugin_2 plugin_2)`

Comment: @KamilCuk, The `add_subdirectory` will be done in the root CMake file. The plugins don't know about each other. Maybe they weren't in the same directory.

Comment: then add plugin_2 before plugin_1. Or remove `::`. `The plugins don't know about each other` but `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Project::plugin_2)` clearly makes plugin_1 know about plugin_2.

Comment: @KamilCuk could you explain the consequence of adding `::`?

Comment: The consequence is that it has to be a target.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I don't want to CMake fail when we don't have the `plugin_2`, just want to ignore it. By the way, the `if(TARGET plugin_2)` even doesn't work and I couldn't find that we have the `plugin_2` or it is not just added to the project by the root CMake.

Comment: "the `if(TARGET plugin_2)` even doesn't work" - If I correctly understand your situation, this check doesn't work because you add (via `add_subdirectory`) the plugin `plugin_1`, which could contain that check, **before** adding the plugin `plugin_2`. This "disorder" is not a problem for CMake, since it evaluates targets at the end of whole configuration process. But it is a problem for you, because at the time `plugin_1` is processed, it doesn't know whether top-level `CMakeLists.txt` does intend to add `plugin_2` or does not.

Comment: Instead of checking targets, you could check plugins' existence in some other way. E.g. top-level `CMakeLists.txt` could construct **full list** of available plugins, and only then perform `add_subdirectory` calls. So every plugin could check that list for dependent plugins. Alternatively, every plugin may report its dependencies to the top-level via some CACHE or PARENT_SCOPE variable. So top-level `CMakeLists.txt` could verify that all dependencies are available and/or load required plugins from some other source.